# Chromecast factory reset improper functioning

Tags: connection, internet-connection, chromecast

My Chromecast device does not get into an AP mode, but keeps searching and trying to connect to a network.  Even after factory reset, the problem does not go away.  The setup page always shows "Connecting to network" and then ends up with a message Chromecast XXXX tried to, but couldn't connect.....

How do I fix this problem?